# Hapi send request to current local server

Tags: hapi.js

I have a `graphql` running on my server. And I have an upload route like this:

```
server.route({
    config: {
        cors: {
            origin: ['*'],
            credentials: true
        },
        payload: {
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true,
            maxBytes: 50869457,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        },
    },
    method: ['POST', 'PUT'],
    path: '/uploadAvatar',
    handler: (request, reply) => {
        const data = request.payload;
        data.identity = options.safeGuard.authenticate(request);

        // REQUEST TO THE SAME SERVER THIS IS RUNNING ON
    }
});
```

I want to send a request to the same server as I am in if that makes sense.. How to do that?

btw I want to call `localhost:3004/graphql` if it's running on `localhost:3004` but on production it's running on port `80`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hapi's built in server.inject method for handling internal routing, the docs for inject are [here](https://hapijs.com/api#serverinjectoptions-callback)